# How to insert data from multiple sql queries into 1 row in a table?

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a visual studio report that runs every weeknight and it generates a PDF with different sales info. For example: total sales amount, total orders, total inventory breakdown, etc. All these numbers are pulled from different tables using different queries. What I want to do is have all the queries run every night, and have the data stored in a new line for each date in a table.

Here is an example of how I'd like it to look.

```
Date       Sales     Orders     Inventory Value
1/1/2017   5,000     50         10,000
1/2/2017   6,000     60         9000
1/3/2017   5,500     55         8500
```

So each line would be a day, and there would be columns for each of my values that my queries pull. I'm not sure how to go about this. I attempted a union all but all my data was being put into new lines instead of all of the data from that given day on that line together.

Any ideas how to achieve something like this?

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are using.

Comment: Howdy, some sample data and source table structure is needed to answer this effectively. In the meantime, this is going to be a `join`, not a `union`

Answer (score 0):

Use several cte, one for each function

```
WITH [Sales] as (
       SELECT date, sales 
       .... <your query>

), [Orders]  as (
       SELECT date, Orders
       .... <your query>

), [Inventory Value]  as (
       SELECT date, Inventory
       .... <your query>
)
SELECT S.[date], S.[Sales], O.[Orders], I.[Inventory]
FROM [Sales] S
JOIN [Orders] O ON S.[date] = O.[date]
JOIN [Inventory Value] I ON S.[date] = I.[date]
```